# How can we use datediff in cubejs for mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, cube

I want to use `datediff` in cubejs -> dimensions, it works with sql but it is not working with mongodb, here is for the sql:

```
dimensions: {
   expiringIn: {
       sql: `DATEDIFF(hour, GETDATE(), ${CUBE.expiryDate})`,
       type: `number`,
   },
 }
```

when I try to use the same method for mongodb, it gives an error, what is the equivalent method name for mongo?

Comment: Did you look for `$dateDiff`?

Comment: Thanks, I use dateDiff as you suggested with the following approach: expiringInMinutes: sql: `dateDiff('${new Date().toISOString()}', ${CUBE}.expiryDate) * 24 * 60`

Comment: Why do you think, you can use `$dateDiff` on **strings**? You must provide `Date` objects.